# How can I use fread() on a binary file to read the data into a std::vector?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, ifstream, fread

Follow-up question on an earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136992/why-does-my-program-crash-when-using-fread-in-the-constructor) I had, that has been perfectly answered. To quickly recap, I had trouble creating a class holding a huge array (stack overflow error). In the answers, some users recommended I use std::vector instead.

The function to read in the data looks like this:

```
Test()
{
   memset(myarray, 0, sizeof(myarray));
   FILE* fstr = fopen("myfile.dat", "rb");
   size_t success= fread(myarray, sizeof(myarray), 1, fstr);
   fclose(fstr);
}
```

for a myarray which looked like this:

```
int myarray[45000000];
```

My question is: How can I read this into a preferable:

```
std::vector<int> myvector;
```

I searched google , and have found multiple answers, usually pointing to the following code:

```
std::ifstream input("myfile.dat", std::ios::in | std::ifstream::binary);
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(input), 
     std::istream_iterator<int>(), 
     std::back_inserter(myvector));
```

After implementing this, and when calling myvector.size() I get 16 (for whatever reason), and accessing a vector element leads to an immediate crash for going out of the vector bounds.

So what do I have to do to get this right? I once read somewhere that I could just simply use the "old" method, and then reading the array into the vector, but this seems to defeat the purpose of using the vector in the first place.

Comment: `istream_iterator` does formatted input. If your file is in binary format, that's not what you want.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan: Way to not read the question at all.  @MarkAnderson: `std::istream_iterator<int>` does _formatted_ reads, and the old `fread` is an _unformatted_ read. You need to do an unformatted read into the vector.

Comment: Then away goes my comment - I'm more a C guy anyways :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fread()` reads your file *binary*, while `ifstream_iterator` tries to extract *formatted* ints (like `42`).

You want to `resize` your `vector` and use [`input.read(...)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) instead:

```
const size_t size = 45000000; // change this to the appropriate value
std::vector<char> myvector(size, 0);
std::ifstream input("myfile.dat", std::ios::in | std::ifstream::binary);
input.read(&myvector[0], myvector.size());
```

Note that you need to use a `std::vector<char>` since `read` expects the first parameter to be a `char *`. You can use other types `T` if you cast the type correctly:

```
input.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&myvector[0]), myvector.size() * sizeof(T));
```

Comment: Would you need to call free() on &myvector[0] after you're done?

Comment: @OliverCiappara No. You *never* want to call `free` on `&myvector[0]` or `myvector.data()` for any `std::vector`. `std::vector` handles allocation and deallocation on its own. Remember: if you didn't call `malloc`, you must not call `free` (unless the function's documentation tells you to use the latter, e.g. `strdup` in POSIX).

Answer (score 3):

If you're using C++ you should try to avoid using the C `FILE` APIs all together -- so you're on the right track. The problem you're having is that `istream_iterator` reads input as text, not binary -- it's expecting ASCII digits. This this out instead:

```
std::vector<int> vec(45000000);

std::filebuf fb;
fb.open("myfile.dat", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary);
fb.sgetn((char*)&vec[0], vec.size() * sizeof(vec[0]));
```